# is x.x.0.x/24 a valid network ip address?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4

I just began learning networking and in a youtube tutorial there is a problem and the answer is not free. So there are these networks:

network A:

- ip: 172.16.0.0/24
- devices: one with an ip of 172.16.0.4 and the other one with 172.16.0.1

network B :

- ip: 172.16.1.0/24
- devices: one with an ip of 172.16.1.1 and the other one with 172.16.1.7

network C:

- ip: 172.16.2.0/30
- devices: one with an ip of 172.16.2.1 and the other one with 172.16.2.20

And the setup is like this:
(N for network)
NA => router => NC => router => NB

and the problem is:
A device in NA is unable to communicate with a device in NB. Why are they unable to communicate?

My answer to this problem is:
network A has an ip of 172.16.**0**.0/24. it can't use this ip because it is a broadcast ip along with 172.16.255.0/24.
I am very doubtful that I'm right so I'm hoping someone could help me.
I googled and I didn't found anything. I think I didn't know how to ask.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is x.x.0.x/24 a valid network ip address?

Yes, it is a valid network address.

> it can't use this ip [172.16.0.0/24] because it is a broadcast ip along with 172.16.255.0/24

No, that's completely wrong.

IP addresses are read from left to right – if it's a /24 network, then the first 24 bits are the "network" part and the **last** 8 bits are the "host" part. An address only becomes a subnet 'broadcast' address if its *host* bits (i.e. the *rightmost* bits) are all-ones, whereas the network bits are completely irrelevant.

(For example, `x.y.z.255/24` or `x.y.255.255/16` would be a broadcast address, but `x.y.7.255/16` would *not* be a broadcast address.)

But in your post, the address only has a "255" in the middle (at the end of the network part), and that has no significance at all on its own – it's just a small part of a completely ordinary network ID. The entire network prefix, `172.16.255/24`, works as a single number.

(The only time it would become somewhat significant is if you used very old routers which still used 1980s-era classful routing, where '172.16' was still a class-B prefix and the '255' was the "subnet ID". And even then, subnet ID 255 did not mean "broadcast", only the host ID did.)

So then:

> A device in NA is unable to communicate with a device in NB. Why are they unable to communicate?

Usually one of the simplest causes:

a) They are missing routes to each other.

b) The router's firewall / ACL rules do not allow this.

Go through every step manually (device A, router NA-NC, router NC-NB, device B, then repeat in the other direction) and look at the devices' routing tables. Remember that routing is not automatically symmetric; each side needs its own routes to the other side.

- What gateway does device A use to reach device B?
- What gateway does router NA-NC use to reach device B?
- What gateway does device B use to reach device A?
- What gateway does router NB-NC use to reach device A?

Use a packet capture tool (such as Wireshark or tcpdump) to see where packets begin to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Network A is not directly connected to Network B - which means it may not know how to get there. The router that Network A is connected to is its gateway - this means that any packet not bound for Network A is forwarded to that router and it needs to figure out what to do with it. This router bridges Network A and Network C, so it knows where to send packets for either subnet - it'll have a route that tells it what to do, and it likely has a default route for where to send packets not bound for either Network A or Network C - but there is a different router/gateway for Network B, so unless it has a route that tells it to use the second router/gateway to forward packets for addresses bound for Network B, it won't know where to send the packets and it'll go out the default route. Assuming that default route is the Internet or some other network segment, it likely doesn't point back to Network B at any point and so will never make it.